# transform file with key value (comma separated) into a file with only values

Tags: file, awk, sed, transform

I have the following file -

```
k11=v11,k12=v12,k13=v13,...,k1N=v1N
k21=v21,k22=v22,k23=v23,...,k2N=v2N
...
...
```

Note that key and values can be alphanumerics. I want a quick way to generate another file
with the following content -

```
v11,v12,v13,..,v1N
v21,v22,v23,..,v2N
....
```

Can I use sed or awk to do this quickly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With GNU `sed`:

```
sed -r 's/(^|,)[^=]+=/\1/g'
```

Explanation:

- `(^|,)` represents either the beginning of a line (`^`) or a coma. Owing to the parentheses, this is stored in register #1.
- `[^=]+=` represents a string made of any character except the equal sign (`[^=]`), at least one character long (`+`) and directly followed by an equal sign
- Both are replaced by the content of register #1 (`s/.../\1/`). In effect, this removes the second part
- The `g` flag at the end repeats the operation as much as necessary

A shorter form: `sed -r 's/[^,=]+=//g'`

POSIX-friendly, if you don't have GNU sed: `sed 's/[^,=]\+=//g'`

Comment: The equivalent in perl: `perl -pe 's/\w+=//g' file.csv`

Answer (score 2):

Here is an awk:

```
awk -F, '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
          split($i,a,/=/)
          printf "%s%s", a[2], (i<NF ? FS : ORS)
        }
    }'  file > new_file
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option using awk is to remove any character except a comma or equals sign using a negated character class `[^,=]+` or matching only alphanumerics using `[[:alnum:]]+=`

---

`$ cat file`

```
k11=v11,k12=v12,k13=v13
k21=v21,k22=v22,k23=v23
```

**Awk**

```
awk '
gsub(/[^=,]+=/,"")
' file > output

cat output
```

**Output**

```
v11,v12,v13
v21,v22,v23
```